# A fatal error has been occurred while running JavaFx native bundle executable on Virtual Machine

Tags: javafx-2, virtual-machine, fatal-error, coredump

I have build `JavaFx` code, deployed and wrapped into self contained `JavaFX` application using `Ant` build.xml on `Windows 7`, x64 `Desktop Machine`. Please see below for more system information -

```
 Operating System: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit (6.1, Build 7600) (7600.win7_gdr.110622-1503)
           Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: INTEL_
       System Model: DH61WW__
               BIOS: BIOS Date: 02/18/11 15:38:44 Ver: 04.06.04
          Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2100 CPU @ 3.10GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.1GHz
             Memory: 4096MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 4074MB RAM
```

When I am running my native bundle `JavaFX` application on any Desktop x64 Machine, it works absolutely fine. But when I am run the same native bundle `JavaFX` application on `Virtual Machine`, it gets started/launched successfully. But on clicking any button or closing the stage, it shows (Not Responding) and throws a fatal error. And finally application gets crashed.

Virtual Machine's system Information -

```
Operating System: Windows Web Server 2008 R2 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1 (7601.win7sp1_gdr.110622-1506)
           Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation
       System Model: Virtual Machine
               BIOS: BIOS Date: 05/05/08 20:35:56  Ver: 08.00.02
          Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q9400  @ 2.66GHz, ~2.7GHz
             Memory: 3072MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 3072MB RAM
          Page File: 2457MB used, 3683MB available
```

You can download the attached [Error](http://mytestexamplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/hs_err_pid4016.log?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAINHDRCMKC5GUSNFA&Expires=1519756149&Signature=hYJ9xFRU2Ce2lLfC757/U5XBXvc=) File. For quick look -

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6dd5fe2d, pid=4016, tid=4292
#
# JRE version: 7.0_10-b18
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.6-b04 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [glass.dll+0xfe2d]  Java_com_sun_glass_events_KeyEvent__1getKeyCodeForChar+0x134d
#
# Core dump written. Default location: C:\Users\apancholi\Desktop\JavaFXJavaHeapMemoryFixes\JavaHeapSample-201302250\app\hs_err_pid4016.mdmp
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Please suggest what is happening here?

FYI: I am passing these VM arguments : -Xms500m -Xmx1g -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:MaxPermSize=250m

Comment: you should file a bug at javafx-jira.kenai.com with all info and crash log. It's hardly possible to find out crash reason for non-developers of the product.

Comment: @SergeyGrinev Yes. Sure. I will file a bug. I just want to know is this issue due to Virtual Machine?

Comment: It can be. Also `Windows Web Server 2008 R2 64-bit` is not in the list of the supported systems: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html

Comment: @SergeyGrinev Yes. Thanks. It has been mentioned that Microsoft Hypervisor is not certified. Hyper-V operates both as a standalone solution and as an addition to Windows Server 2008 R2. Thus it may not run properly on Windows Server 2008 R2 because it's not certified. Can I get more confirmation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are next possibilities:

- there is an issue with virtual environment
- `Windows Web Server 2008 R2 64-bit` may not be supported, see list of the supported platforms here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html

In any case it's hardly possible to find out crash reason for non-developers of the product. Please, file an issue at http://javafx-jira.kenai.com

Answer (score 2):

I also had that problem in my application then I install "Desktop Experience" under Server Manager in Windows 2008 R2. then I could solve my problem 
Here are the steps to do it: 
Go to Server Manager 
Expand Features and Click add features
select Desktop Experience and install it

It will fix your problem